# Convert text format to json in WSO2 stream processor/ regex for custom text mapping in WSO2SP

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have a wso2 stream processor code where i am receiving **input from kafka** as **text** format because debezium mongodb connector gives out a lengthy output and it's *not a valid json to send to WSO2*. So, i am receiving it as text and plans to use regex to get only the part of payload i need.
I am not able to figure out how to convert this text format to json so that i can send it to another kafka stream and do custom json mapping on this.

Another approach i am trying:
I am also trying custom mapping for text:

```
@source(type='kafka',
        topic.list='demo',
        partition.no.list='0',
        threading.option='single.thread',
        group.id="group",
        bootstrap.servers='localhost:9092',
 @map(type='text',fail.on.missing.attribute='false', regex.A='(.*)',
                @attributes(id = 'A[0]')))
define stream transactionstream1(id string);
```

Sample Json:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"342fs"},"code":"ffssefse","name":"test1","desc":"description1","transRefId":"esfef3423des","amount":1000,"currency":"INR","requestId":null,"redeemedCashcode":null,"sender":{"id":"5d9c0dedcf71a09664922042","name":"tat","phone":"3242324"}}
```

**Regex to get code attribute from above json is** : **`(?:"code":")(.*?)(?:")`**    but wso2 **regex.A** is not accepting this.

Thats why currently i am getting entire data in text format and trying to convert to json

Is there some other approach to this? or **some other convention of writing regex** in wso2 stream processor?

I need to get individual attributes in custom mapping from text from the above json in wso2sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your regex consist of ", you need to escape that using 3 double quotes as follows,

```
 regex.A = """(?:"code":")(.*?)(?:")""",
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. I was struggling since yesterday to get this working in wso2.
I have one more question.
Can we use regex in wso2 to replace " / " with " " ? @Niveathika

Comment: Yes, you can use str:replaceAll() /str:replaceFirst() as per your need, https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-execution-string/api/5.0.9/#replaceall-function

Comment: I have a few more questions. I am trying to get kafka input as text format, where i filter out a part of it with regex and then send it to another stream where i want to do custom mapping. I am not able to figure out how to do custom mapping in another stream here? @Niveathika

Comment: Mappers are only at the receiving/publishing parts i.e mappers can only be coupled with sources/sinks. After you extract part of it to a stream attribute, you can only use siddhi extensions to manipulate such str:.., json:..

Comment: If i send this event to another kafka topic and receive it in a new stream then it's possible? or i will have to do all the tasks at my initial source stream where i receive this text?

Comment: If you send it and receive it, you will receive only what you have extracted, but IMO is unnecessary processing, you can use https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-execution-json/api/2.0.4/ to process from transactionstream1

Comment: I am receiving data from kafka topics in text format, will json execution api work in this scenario ?

Comment: What I meant was you can use JSON API if you have extracted JSON from the text you were receiving or you can use string if you have extracted a string